# Deploy Cloud Storage Triggers in Multi-Region Buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, gcloud

I am trying to deploy a Cloud Storage trigger by following the guide here:
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage#object_finalize

I want to listen for any finalization in my default "us multi-region" bucket. Unfortunately, when I try to deploy the function trigger via gcloud cli as described in the link above:

```
gcloud functions deploy **** \
--gen2 \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=**** \
--trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket={my-multi-region-bucket}"
```

I get the following error:

```
INVALID_ARGUMENT: Cannot create trigger ****: 
Bucket '****' is in location 'us', but the trigger location is 'us-central1'.
The trigger must be in the same location as the bucket. 
Try redeploying and changing the trigger location to 'us'.
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally got it working by simply adding the `--trigger-location=us` as shown below:

```
gcloud functions deploy **** \
--gen2 \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=**** \
--trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--trigger-event-filters="bucket={my-multi-region-bucket}" \
--trigger-location=us
```

Comment: Thanks big $ - saved me debugging time with this one